# How to optimize the electric vehicle charging cost using Gekko?

Tags: python, minimize, gekko, cost-based-optimizer

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np              
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


m = GEKKO()         
m.options.SOLVER = 1 
m.options.IMODE = 3

Num_car = 1
TOU = [64.9,64.9,64.9,64.9,64.9,64.9,64.9,64.9,152.6,239.8,239.8,152.6,239.8,239.8,239.8,239.8,152.6,152.6,152.6,152.6,152.6,152.6,152.6,64.9]
n=len(TOU)
p_i = m.Array(m.Var,(n,Num_car))

input = m.Array(m.Var, (n), value = 0.0, lb = 0.0, ub = 7.0, integer = True)

SOC_t = m.Array(m.Var,(n, Num_car))

for tt in range(0,n):
    for i in range(0,Num_car):
            SOC_t[tt,i].lower = 30  
            SOC_t[tt,i].upper = 70  

SOC_t[0,0] = 30

eq_car_bat = np.zeros((n))
eq_car_bat = list(eq_car_bat)

for tt in range(0,n):
        eq_car_bat[tt] = SOC_t[tt] + input[tt] == p_i[tt]

m.Equation(eq_car_bat)

SOC_Max = 90
SOC_Min = 30
sum_soc = sum(SOC_t[tt])

eq_total = np.zeros((n))
eq_total = list(eq_total)

eq_total = sum_soc == SOC_Max

m.Equation(eq_total)

for i in range(n):
    m.Minimize(TOU[i]*p_i[i])

m.options.IMODE = 3
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)
```

I want to find minimized charging costs when the EV charging.
My code is shown below but, I received the following error "x must be a python list of GEKKO parameters, variables, or expressions" that I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The intention appears to be to decide when to charge a battery over a 24 hour time period given a specific Time of Use (TOU). Here is a modified version of the script that charges (integer values 0-7) from 30 to 70 on the SOC. It has the capability to add additional vehicles but there is currently only one.

[image: SOC]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np              
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

m = GEKKO()         
m.options.SOLVER = 1 
m.options.IMODE = 3

Num_car = 1
TOU = [64.9,64.9,64.9,64.9,64.9,64.9,64.9,64.9,152.6,239.8,
       239.8,152.6,239.8,239.8,239.8,239.8,152.6,152.6,
       152.6,152.6,152.6,152.6,152.6,64.9]
n=len(TOU)
inp = m.Array(m.Var, (n), value = 0.0, 
                lb = 0.0, ub = 7.0, integer = True)

SOC_Min = 30; SOC_Max = 90
# set bounds 30-90
SOC_t = m.Array(m.Var,(n, Num_car),lb=SOC_Min,ub=SOC_Max)

# set new bounds 30-70
for tt in range(0,n):
    for j in range(Num_car):
        SOC_t[tt,j].lower = 30  
        SOC_t[tt,j].upper = 70  

for j in range(Num_car):
    # initial SOC
    m.Equation(SOC_t[0,j]==30)   # initial charge at start
    m.Equation(SOC_t[n-1,j]==70) # desired charge at end
    for tt in range(1,n):
        m.Equation(SOC_t[tt,j] == SOC_t[tt-1,j] + inp[tt])

for tt in range(n):
    m.Minimize(TOU[tt]*inp[tt])

m.options.IMODE = 3
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
for j in range(Num_car):
    p = np.empty(n)
    for tt in range(n):
        p[tt] = SOC_t[tt,j].value[0]
    plt.plot(p,'r.-',label='vehicle '+str(j+1))
plt.legend(); plt.ylabel('SOC'); plt.grid()

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
p = np.empty(n)
for tt in range(n):
    p[tt] = inp[tt].value[0]
plt.plot(p,'ko-',label='charge rate')
plt.legend(); plt.ylabel('charge'); plt.grid()

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(TOU,'bs-',label='electricity price')
plt.ylabel('price'); plt.grid()
plt.legend(); plt.xlabel('Time (hr)')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('soc_results.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

This problem is related to some of the other problems in the [Energy Benchmarks](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EnergyBenchmarks). Gekko has the capability to manage the time aspect of the problem when using `IMODE=6` instead of indexing time explicitly. Using `IMODE=3` (default) gives more control over the problem structure. `IMODE=6` is better if there are differential equations.